# How to remove a zombie directory in Azure

Tags: azure

My profile only has a default directory

[image]

Strangely, when I use `azure document intelligence`, it picks an old directory which I believe I deleted quite a while ago

[image]

I tried to switch the current directly but it isn't working and reverts back. Due to this, `document intelligence` isn't starting up. How do I get rid of the zombie directory which is showing in `document intelligence` but not in `azure` portal.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a configuration or cache issue causing the problem. try this in your azure CLI and hope this gets it fixed.

```html
az account show
az account list --output table
az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
```

Now replace  with the correct subscription ID. Make sure the subscription you want is set as the default.

Dont forget to clear the cache using CLI

```html
rm -rf ~/.azure
```

After clearing try running the command again hope it gets it solved.,

Comment: tried but didn't work. `Azure Document intelligence studio ` is a different portal than `azure` portal - https://documentintelligence.ai.azure.com/studio